# Java - Sending file over HTTP Server

Tags: java, rest, https, httpserver

I made a HTML server using `com.sun.net.httpserver` library. I want to send a jar file to the client to make them download it.

This method below actually make the client download the file:

```
@Override
public void handle(HttpExchange httpExchange) {
    File file = new File("Test.jar");
    try {
        httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, file.length());
        OutputStream outputStream = httpExchange.getResponseBody();
        Files.copy(file.toPath(), outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but it sends the jar file as a zip. How do I get it to send it as a jar file instead? And is there a better way to send files?

Comment: Why not setting up a sftp server if it‘s just about providing files for download? For pure development purpose you could also simply launch a http via python webserver at the files location (assuming network is secured/internal) with python3 -m http.server

Comment: It is not just about providing files, server responds JSON data aswell (via some other context obviously).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try adding the following to get correct filename for the download:

```
httpExchange.getResponseHeaders().add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Test.jar");
```

You might also want do add the following to get the corrent [content-type](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/http-headers-content-type/):

```
httpExchange.setAttribute(HTTPExchange.HeaderFields.Content_Type.toString(), "application/java-archive");
```

Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types for a listing of content-types for different suffixes.

Comment: adding Content-Disposition fixed it, thank you. But just curious, what does that second part do? It works without adding it

Comment: @EyüpYıldız Thanks for asking! I have updated my answer. The last one is to get the correct content-type.

Comment: you guys, both OP and answer owner helps me a lot. Thank you so much.